# Do embassy workers have access to my financial information?

Tags: visas, embassies, consulates

Applying for a tourist visa

The government where this embassy is located in obviously knows my assets in the country.

US also knows my assets in their country.

**Can the embassy worker who'd interview me for my visa allowed too see this information on their screen?**

What about other countries? Say UK or EU

I think they are not allowed to see the information, which is why they ask people to bring printouts of their financial documents

Comment: For UK applications, financial evidence has to be submitted with the application. There is no interview as such, other than to give biometrics and hand in supporting documents. So yes, IMHO it’s safe to presume embassy staff who deal with visa applications will be able to see your information. They can presumably also make enquiries with banks etc to verify the information, if they so wish.

Comment: @user124571 your question is vague. You also mention “other countries like EU or UK” when you have not mentioned a specific country initially. You refer to the US, but it’s unclear if that is an example or if it is indeed the country you are applying for a tourist visa from. You also state that governments “known your assets in their country”, which is not necessary true, at least not in a systematic and automated fashion. What they have available at the e tip of their fingers and what they could get if they really wanted to can be very different things.

Comment: But, whatever happens, your question seems like you want them not to know about your actual assets. Trying to lie or omit required information is **never** a good idea. Even without extensive and immediate access to all your financials, it’s often very easy to detect incorrect information. That’s why most countries require multiple sources of information (e.g. bank statements and pay slips) to corroborate them, and people who try to provide false or incomplete information are usually caught quite quickly because they are often not able to paint a consistent and credible picture.

Comment: "obviously"??? Do you believe the government has hacked all the banks so they can see everyone's account information?  Or do you believe the banks hand it over universally and willingly without a warrant, like the world just works that way?  Not in the US, I don't think.

Comment: "Embassy workers" is generic. In general they do not have such information (and also they do not ask them. Do not confuse the question about you have sufficient fund as the requirement to give them all your financial situation. But countries may have many other information (and after 11/9 many financial information are shared, with some constraint). So some intelligence worker in embassy may have the information). Embassy workers may do a background check and find many information about you (legally or just easily found with a short search).

Comment: @Traveller "They can presumably also make enquiries with banks etc to verify the information" wait what??? Do you have a link or any kind of source on this? This would be absolutely insane, if random government workers could just call a bank to obtain your financial information.

Comment: @Ruslan Not to ‘any random government employee’, no. However it is a general principle of banking confidentiality obligations that a bank may divulge information about its customer where eg the bank is compelled by law (court orders, statute or regulation) to disclose the information, or where the bank has a public duty to disclose the information. The latter could well apply in cases where visa applications are being verified. Note: ex-retail bank employee, IANAL

Comment: You should check the small print: if you fill in an application for a visa or passport you may by signing and submitting the application give them permission to access certain information. It's obviously not going to be accessible to most staff (although it's always possible a cleaner might see something on a desk), and I'd be surprised in most cases if they did more than read your documents and run you through some basic lists of known outlaws, but if they suspect you are lying or breaking the law, then you have no expectation of privacy.

Answer (score 25):

Take it from somebody working in enterprise IT: **there is no one set of "the information"**. Even in a single country, there are thousands of databases maintained by dozens of government departments, each with different bits of info and different access controls.  All of them are hard to correlate with each other, so much so that it's very difficult to search for anything (like, say, a name, much less a specific person) across them.  Every now and then some bureaucrat decides this is intolerable and sets out to build a new unified system, which just adds yet another layer of cruft to the creaky pile.  All this applies to systems in a single country: the complexity of trying to coordinate access across multiple countries is considerably worse.

To get back to your question: the officer handling your visa application *will* have access to some key info, like your immigration history for that country.  They'll *probably* have access to some terrorist watchlist type systems that *may* cross country boundaries, like the US/UK/etc Five Eyes system, and they *may* be able to request searches into others if something catches their eye.   But, no, they will not have any sort of instant access to your private financial records in a foreign country.

Comment: But they can call up issuing agencies (banks etc) to verify genuiness of documents for background checks during processing. Whether such calls are entertained or not are a different matter.

Comment: @RedBaron Banks will not release info about their customers without a subpoena or equivalent, least of all to a foreign government.

Comment: [Re: your first paragraph](https://xkcd.com/927/)

Comment: No subpoena is needed. Instead,the visa application might contain something like "I, the applicant, hereby declare everything I wrote is true and I also authorise Country-I-want-to-get-into to verify the validity of enclosed documents." That doesn't give access to any extra information,but it's enough to let the bank say "Yes, that statement is genuine."